# Recognising text and displaying it

Tags: processing

I have programmed a paint application in the processing programming language. I want the letters and/or words I or a user places on the paint application to be recognised and to be printed out in a terminal to start of with.

For example, if the following text is painted on by the user:

[image]

Then the word stack will be printed to the terminal.

Ive googled that natural language can be used. But i'm struggling in applying this, after reading the theory on this.

Any one have any suggestions on easy ways to do this?

Many thanks!

Comment: Could you be a bit more specific about what you want? This is pretty broad.

Comment: I just want words to be recognised and be displayed on the terminal.

Comment: right - could you be more specific about image type, languages / tools you've tried or techniques you've tried or are considering? what did you google? what did you not understand?

Comment: Oh, so I'm using Processing with java to do all this. I have an application like [ms paint][1] where colours can be selected and drawn on the UI. I would like any text like 'stack' i have used above placed by the user to be recognised and displayed in a terminal, just as system.out.println to start of with. So far i have looked at http://tess4j.sourceforge.net/ but it gives no support for what i am trying to do. thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you are talking about is OCR (optical character recognition). A search on DuckDuckGo for "OCR basics optical character recognition" will net you some good links. Try this one: http://www.slideshare.net/document_imaging_scanning/basics-ofopticalcharacterrecognition.

best of luck. 
mike.

Comment: could you include some relevant topics /ideas from the linked resource here in the answer? If the linked page goes away, this answer's value drops to near zero.

Comment: @AndyJones I second that.

Comment: Also note that OCR gets quite a bit more difficult when it has to cope with handwriting recognition as well... OCR has a hard enough time coping with Times New Roman when you have noisy scans, rotation, skew, and other things going on... In other words, this is not just a "oh, if I write these couple dozen lines of code" kind of thing...

Comment: I think the real question here is where is this character recognition going to be taking place. If the image is loaded from a source image file then the task is very difficult and requires complex image processing algorithms. IF the letters are being captured live then the best bet is to break each letter into strokes (pen up/ pen down or change of direction). These strokes can be interpreted on a grid and possibly compared to a library of stroke characteristics common to each letter in the need language. Essentially snap each stroke to a grid and see it it matches the character you know.